# android studio firebase gettoken id

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am programming a chat app and I want to save the token id in the firebase database but I got the token empty. This is my code:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    String Device_id = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    Toast.makeText(this, Device_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mDatabaseTokenId.child(user_id).child("device_token").setValue(Device_id).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()){

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, ""+task.getException()
                        , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    if(user.isEmailVerified()){

         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
         startActivity(intent);
         finish();
```

The device_id return empty why? please help me, guys.

Comment: if your device have no connection, then it will return null. Make sure onTokenRefresh() is called.

Comment: my device have connection but it still return null ?

Comment: Has ur onTokenRefresh getting called or not  ??

Comment: no, how i can call it?

Comment: No need to call it manually.. have u added the service in AndroidManifest which extends FirebaseInstanceIdService.It is used  to handle the creation and updating of registration tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Add the service in your Manifest

```
 <service
  android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
     </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

You will have a onTokenRefresh method in your Service like below

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}
```

Comment: i do this bro but it dont work, when i create class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService and call onTokenRefresh what i will do then?

Comment: Are you getting any firebase log while launching app??

Comment: Not needed ... I though if you are doing a sample ..I can help you out